# Convert Title Case String To A Slug

Tags: apex

My regex is not very good, but does anyone have a method to converting a "titled-cased" string to a ""slugified string? For example:

`MyComponentName` would transform/manipulate to `my-component-name`

So I could do something like:

```
public static String slugify(String s){
   /* Do Stuff... split at capital letter? */
   return s;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static String slugify(String s) {
    return String.join(s.split('(?=[A-Z])'),'-').toLowerCase();
}
```

How this works:

We break the string apart into capitalized words, join them back together with hyphens, convert them all to lowercase.

Comment: Make sure you're running a recent API version on your class; in my org using exec anonymous, it doesn't include a hyphen up front. Otherwise, you can also use removeStart to remove it (either before or after toLowerCase).

Answer (score 4):

Try something like the following:

```
static final Pattern caseChangePattern = Pattern.compile('[A-Z]?[a-z]+');
public static String slugify(String input)
    Matcher caseChangeMatcher = caseChangePattern.matcher(input);
    List<String> slugs = new List<String>();
    while (caseMatcher.find())
        slugs.add(caseMatcher.group().toLowerCase());
    return String.join(slugs, '-');
}
```

You can see some of the outputs:

```
system.assertEquals('my-component-name', slugify('MyComponentName'));
system.assertEquals('my-component-name', slugify('myComponentName'));
system.assertEquals('my-component-name', slugify('My Component Name'));
```

The reason I made a leading capital optional is that you may want to slugify method names which start with a lower-case letter, for example.

Comment: This works, but it's also the slowest possible method because of all the looping and so on that you're responsible for. I really did the answer from @bigassforce, as it demonstrated a really cool replaceAll syntax that I doubt many people know about.

Comment: @sfdcfox I didn't even realize `split` accepts a regex. I think a diversity of approaches is good, and agree this is slower. Not sure why his answer was deleted...